# Error when calling keras in R with keras_model_sequential()

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I want to use Keras in R but, already install anaconda, then in R run

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

to start the installation process, but when I want to use the library using  `keras_model_sequential()` it shows the following error.

how can i fix it??

```
  > model_keras <- keras_model_sequential()
    Error: ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\maty\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\maty\ANACON~1\envs\R-TENS~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Error en una rutina de inicializaciÃ³n de biblioteca
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install keras and tensorflow in conda?

I know the general tips you get from online resources are to install anaconda for python, keras and tensorflow, but I approached it from a different way. I didn't install anaconda, just python3.7, which automatically has pip installed. Then I use pip3 install tensorflow and keras, R was able to run keras just fine.